# preventing a table from pushing a float-left div down

Tags: css

I have two float:left divs that are designed to stack left-to-right, one is the classic left nav and has a fixed width declared.  The other is designed to span the rest of the width of the browser and fill 100% of the remaining width.  Currently it does not have a width declared either natively or by any js/jQuery.

The problem comes where there is a table in the second div, which has about 10 columns of tabular results, some of them longer text.  As soon as the cumulative text of the table cells pushes the table width to the size of the div it's in, the div pops under the left nav.

Is there any strategy to basically "tell the table" that it will not expand any wider than the parent div, but instead that text in the cells will wrap?  I'm hoping to NOT have to use JS in any way for this.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftNav" style="width:250px;">
    left<br>nav<br>here<br>        
    </div>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <table>
            <tr><td>about</td><td>10</td><td>Columns and they can contain sentences of text as well, but I'd like to not have the table push the div it's in down below the left nav div.  This illustrates that point!</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#container{
    width:100%;
}
#leftNav{
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:15px;
}
#mainContent{
    float:left;
    background-color:aliceblue;
}
/* nothing more*/
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, can you just set table {max-width: "some width"}

Comment: agree with Tony Tambe.

Comment: You could use `calc()` if you only care about support for IE10+ [like this example](http://jsbin.com/vetuv/1/edit). Or [display:table instead of floats.](http://jsbin.com/tuhic/1/edit) for IE8+

Comment: I apologize, here's js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/54hbnzku/3/
thought the description was enough :)

Comment: @SamuelFullman, any feedback for the answers below?

Comment: @Brian I'm still working on this.  I've only tested in Firefox so far, and to complicate things, if I select table-row or table for display, the top attribute disappears, and also overflow:hidden doesn't seem to work the same, and there are some problems with floats and positioning.  Trust me what I inherited is a soup; I'll circle back on this later thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `display:table` for this layout. The main benefit being that the columns will always line up regardless of their content width.

- `html,body { height: 100%; }` enables percentage heights for the child elements of `<body>`
- The container is given `display: table`
- The two columns are given `display: table-cell`
- The left column is given a fixed width and the right column is given no width

Possible drawback - `display: table` is compatible IE8+

[Read more about the display values on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values).

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
#leftNav {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
}
#mainContent {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
/* nothing more*/
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftNav">left
    <br>nav
    <br>here
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>about</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Columns and they can contain sentences of text as well, but I'd like to not have the table push the div it's in down below the left nav div. This illustrates that point!</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display the two parent div elements as inline tables, the table will be treated as a child table and assume table like behavior of conforming. To have cell values completely conform to the width of the cell, you can use `word-break: break-all;` which will give characters inline like display and break when needed.

```css
div {
    display: inline-table;
    word-break: break-all;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>

<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
      <td>Table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```